# pass constructor object into self invoke function

Tags: javascript, oop

```
#1 //pass obj into self invoke, works fine
var foo = {
    a: 1
};

(function(o){
    console.log(o.a);
})(foo);

#2 //this is not working
var foo = function(){
  this.a = 1; 
};

(function(o){
  console.log(o);
})(foo);
```

I'm new in Javascript, I try to pass an object into self invoke

my problem is when I try to pass constructor obj, its not working

anyone know why?

Comment: Change `})(foo);` to `})(new foo());`

Comment: ha! i forgot to create new obj from constructor obj

Comment: Use a debugger. It's faster and better than crowd-sourced debugging using humans on SO.

Comment: for the second to work, the constructor function should be invoked and returned an object in the first place. It doesn't even have a return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order `#2` to work you have to correct it as follows;

```
var foo = (function(){
  return this.a = 1; 
})();

(function(o){
  console.log(o);
})(foo);
```